# Pandas groupby - Apply conditions on specific groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics

I have to implement a pandas groupby operation which is more difficult than the usual simple aggregates I do. The table I'm working with has the following structure:

```
  category price
0        A    89
1        A    58
2      ...   ...
3        B    75
4        B   120
5      ...   ...
6        C    90
7        C   199
8      ...   ...
```

As shown above, my example DataFrame consists of 3 categories A, B, and C (the real DataFrame I'm working on has ~1000 categories). We will assume that category A has 20 rows and categories B and C have more than 100 rows. These are denoted by the 3 dots (...).

I would like to calculate the average price of each category **with the following conditions**:

- If the number of elements in the category is greater than 100 (i.e., B and C in this example), then the average should be calculated while excluding values that are 3 standard deviations away from the mean **within each category**.
- Else, for the categories that have less than 100 elements (i.e., A in this example), the average should be calculated on the entire group, without any exclusion criteria.

Calculating the average price for each category without any condition on the groups is straightforward: `df.groupby("category").agg({"price": "mean"})`, but I'm stuck with the extra conditions here.

I also always try to provide a reproducible example while asking questions here but I don't know how to properly write one for this problem with fake data. I hope this format is still ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do it like this?

```
df.groupby('category')['price'].apply(
      lambda x: np.mean(x) if len(x) <= 100 
                else np.mean(x[(x >= np.mean(x) - 3*np.std(x))
                               & (x <= np.mean(x) + 3*np.std(x))]))
```

Or without numpy (but with numpy usually works faster):

```
df.groupby('category')['price'].apply(
      lambda x: x.mean() if len(x) <= 100 
              else x[(x >= x.mean() - 3*x.std()) 
                     & (x <= x.mean() + 3*x.std())].mean())
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you will be able to do all of this at once. Try to break down the steps, like this:

1. Identify the number of elements per category:

```
df_elements = df.groupby('category').agg({'price':'count'}).reset_index()
df_elements.rename({'price':'n_elements'}, inplace=True,axis=1)
```

2. Identify if the number of elements is less than 100 or greater than 100 and then perform the appropriate average calculation:

```
aux = []
for cat in df_elements.category.unique():
    if df_elements[df_elements.category==cat]['n_elements'] < 100:
        df_aux = df[df.category==cat].groupby('category').agg({'price':'mean'})
        aux.append(df_aux.reset_index())
    else:
        std_cat = df[df.category==cat]['price'].std()
        mean_cat = df[df.category==cat]['price'].mean()
        th = 3*std_cat
        df_cut = df[(df.category==cat) & (df.price <= mean_cat + th) & (df.price >= mean_cat - th]
        df_aux = df_cut.groupby('category').agg({'price':'mean'})
        aux.append(df_aux.reset_index())

final_df = pd.concat(aux,axis=0)
final_df.rename({'price':'avg_price'},axis=1,inplace=True)
```